# Django Как строить "зеркальную матрицу"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Здравствуйте.

Ломаю себе голову уже сутки, и кажется, что вот вот закипевшие мозги начнут вытекать через уши.

Задача кажется элементарной, но у меня категорически не получается её решить.

Есть такая модель:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Latency(models.Model):
    city_from = models.ForeignKey('cities_light.City', 
        related_name='city_from',
    )
    city_to = models.ForeignKey('cities_light.City',
        related_name='city_to',
    )
    latency = models.FloatField(default=0,
        verbose_name=_('Latency')
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)
```

Задача, построить таблицу примерно следующего вида:

```
X       Минск Москва Воронеж
Минск   X     340    760
Москва  340   X      534
Воронеж 760   534    Х
```

Возможно следует пересмотреть структуру данных.

В упор смотрю на это, и не понимаю, как правильно сделать.

Если у кого-то есть какие-то идеи на этот счёт, буду крайне признателен за поддержку.

Comment: Модель  у Вас подходящая, что не получается? Написать правильный шаблон и view? Или заполнить значениями?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, написать правильный шаблон.
Это должна быть table, но что-то я не понимаю, как правильно сделать.

Comment: Я так понимаю, cities_light.City это у Вас модель City из модуля cities_light? :) Немного странно выглядит - модель в модуле отличном от models.py ... Не критично, но уточняю просто.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, она в модуле models.py, как и должно быть. 
Да, cities.City - это модель CIty из приложения cities_light

Comment: Самый простой вариант тут - через ajax запрашивать json сделанный из queryset по всем Latency, и javascript рисовать таблицу. Я бы так делал...  Динамически на бэкэнде ее тоже можно сделать, но не очевидно как то с этими вложенностями :)

Comment: Я примерно так и делаю. Я сериализованные данные по сигналу отдаю на frontend через websocket.  Весь backend готов. Проблема в том, как это дело отобразить в таблице.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем варианте слишком много запросов к базе идет. Я предлагаю собрать свои словари из базы один раз, одним запросом, а потом работать с ними.

```
dc = {}  # Все сочетания городов и расстояний
dc_name = {}  # Названия городов

for i in Latency.objects.select_related('city_from__city', 'city_to__city').all():
    f, t = (i.city_from.city.pk, i.city_to.city.pk)
    dc["%s_%s" % (f, t)] = i.latency
    dc_name[f] = i.city_from.city.name
    dc_name[t] = i.city_to.city.name
dc_name = [[i, dc_name[i]] for i in dc_name] # Преобразуем из словаря в массив
print("DC >>> ", dc)
print("DC_NAME >>> ", dc_name)

rez = []  # Результат

# Добавляем заголовки
k = ['X']
for i in dc_name:
    k.append(i[1])
rez.append(k)

# Строим саму матрицу
for j in dc_name:
    k = [j[1]]
    for i in dc_name:
        if i[0] == j[0]:
            k.append("X")
        else:
            k.append(
                dc.get("%s_%s" % (i[0], j[0]),   dc.get("%s_%s" % (j[0], i[0]), 'X')   )
            )
    rez.append(k)

print("REZULT >>> ", rez)
```

Результат работы:

```
DC >>>  {'1_3': 760, '1_2': 340, '3_2': 534}
DC_NAME >>>  [[1, 'Минск'], [2, 'Москва'], [3, 'Воронеж']]
REZULT >>>  [['X', 'Минск', 'Москва', 'Воронеж'], ['Минск', 'X', 340, 760], ['Москва', 340, 'X', 534], ['Воронеж', 760, 534, 'X']]
```

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik Помог ли вам данный пример решить задачу, более оптимально?

Answer (score 1):

Может это будет полезно, приведу простой пример со словарями:

```
>>> a = ['min', 'mos', 'vor']
>>> a
['min', 'mos', 'vor']
>>> all = {i: {j: 0 if j == i else int(input('{0} to {1} '.format(i, j))) for j in a} for i in a}
min to mos 340
min to vor 760
mos to min 340
mos to vor 534
vor to min 760
vor to mos 534
>>> all
{'mos': {'mos': 0, 'min': 340, 'vor': 534}, 'min': {'mos': 340, 'min': 0, 'vor': 760}, 'vor': {'mos': 534, 'min': 760, 'vor': 0}}
>>> def example():
...   print('X       {0}  {1}  {2}'.format(*(i for i in all)))
...   for i in all:
...     print(i, '     {0}  {1}  {2}'.format(*(all[i][j] for j in all[i])))
... 
>>> example()
X       mos  min  vor
mos      0  340  534
min      340  0  760
vor      534  760  0
```

Я думаю не сложно доработать и получить то, что Вам нужно

Comment: Так у меня тоже получается :) 
Но с queryset'ами сиутация совсем другая.

Answer (score -1):

Сделал, хоть и уродливо, но сделал:

```
    cities_from = [i for i in set([i.city_from.city.name for i in Latency.objects.all()])]
    cities_to = [i for i in set([i.city_to.city.name for i in Latency.objects.all()])]
    cities = cities_from + cities_to

    matrix = {cf: {ct: Latency.objects.filter(
        Q(city_to__city__name=cf, city_from__city__name=ct) | 
        Q(city_to__city__name=ct, city_from__city__name=cf))[0].latency if Latency.objects.filter(
        Q(city_to__city__name=cf, city_from__city__name=ct) | 
        Q(city_to__city__name=ct, city_from__city__name=cf)).count() > 0 else 0 for ct in cities} 
        for cf in cities}
```

Уверен, что можно лаконичнее, но главное, что работает :)